# Apache and Flask: attempt to invoke directory as script

Tags: python, linux, apache, flask, wsgi

I have an Apache (ver. 2.2.15) server (running on Linux CentOS), where I have a lot of .cgi scripts located in /var/www/cgi-bin, aliased:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin "/var/www/cgi-bin"
```

And it works fine when I enter *mydomain/cgi-bin/something.cgi*.

Now I want to have also Flask application running within Apache server on 80 port. The app is located in /var/www/cgi-bin/app. So, I created simple Flask app - **a.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

and **a.wsgi** file:

```
import sys
import site
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/cgi-bin/app')
site.addsitedir('/var/www/cgi-bin/app:/<my_python_path>/Lib/site-packages')
from app import app as application
```

Also in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf I have created required virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName app.<mydomain>:80
WSGIDaemonProcess app python-path=/var/www/cgi-bin/app:/<my_python_path>/Lib/site-packages user=user1 group=user1 threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /cgi-bin/app /var/www/cgi-bin/app/a.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/cgi-bin/app>
    WSGIProcessGroup app
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/www/cgi-bin/app/logs/error.log
CustomLog  /var/www/cgi-bin/app/logs/custom.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But everytime I try to open *mydomain/cgi-bin/app/* in the error.log file I see this error:

```
(...) attempt to invoke directory as script: /var/www/cgi-bin/app/
```

Do you have an idea what have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You should not put your Flask app under `cgi-bin`, in fact it should not be under the DocumentRoot at all. Move it somewhere else entirely - I like `/srv/`, but it's up to you - and change the WSGI alias appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't think about it. Now the flask app is moved to /home/user/app/a.py. The wsgi file (location without any changes: /var/www/cgi-bin/app/a.wsgi) and httpd.conf now look like this: http://pastebin.com/tWcupwCv 
But unfortunatelly it seems not to work. Do I have some more mistakes in my paths?